# How To Remember Pageview Widget Last Visited Page

Tags: flutter, dart

I am building an Android App using Flutter and Dart.

In this app, I am using a Pageview Widget, the user interact with it, scroll some pages, now when the user leaves the Pageview Widget and go to some other page do some activity there, the user when comes back to the Pageview Widget, the widget starts showing the dynamically created pages, it starts with the first page, here I want to start the index from the page which was last visited by the user.

I have thought of a solution to store the last visited page on DB and retrieving it when the user comes to Pageview Widget and updating it on every page scroll. Is this a good solution? Or there is another way to accomplish this thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution is to save the current page id in shared_preferences then retrieving it when the user revisits the page again.